# R regex just not quite right

Tags: regex, r

I'm having a problem with regex in R. Maybe I've just been looking at it too long. I've got strings of the form

```
'thing1 - thing2'
'thingA - thingB'
```

where the first is separated from the second by a space, a dash, and another space. The first thing is a combination of letters, digits, slashes, and periods; the second can be the same, or not exist (in which case there is also no separating dash). I want to use `regmatches` with `gregexpr` to find patterns matching the first and second parts. That's something like

```
regmatches(
  'thing1 - thing2',
  gregexpr('^(\\w|\\s|\\.|/)+(\\s-\\s){0,1}', 'thing1 - thing2', perl=T)
)
```

Fine and well. But sometimes `thing1` is tricky, with a dash with no spaces (eg `10-43`), or it can be the exact string `Blue - MC`, which obviously messes up the "separate by `\\s-\\s`" rule. And I just can't seem to get the regex right! I tried

```
regmatches(
  c('10-43', 'Blue - MC'),
  gregexpr(
    '^\\w(\\w|\\s|\\.|/\\S-\\S)+\\s-\\s{0,1}|^Blue\\s-\\sMC', 
    c('10-43', 'Blue - MC'), perl=T
  )
)
```

and I get `c('10', 'Blue')`. Help? Thanks!

and

Comment: You really should provide more examples of input/desired output. So you want to allow no spaces. You just want everything to the left of a dash and to the right? There will always be a dash?

Comment: If there are two items to separate, they will always be separated by spacedashspace.

Comment: What do you want to return of there is not? How do you want the data returned?

Comment: If there isn't a second item, ie there is no spacedashspace, I want to return everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you said you want to use `gregexpr` and `regmatches`, but why not `strsplit` since all you're doing is splitting the strings that will *"always be separated by a space-dash-space"*?

Per your comment, you can split at space-dash-space, but keep `Blue - MC` by simply removing `Blue - MC` from the list before applying the split. Then you can add it back in afterward.

```
> things <- c('thing1 - thing2', 'thingA - thingB', 'thingC', 'Blue - MC')
> w <- which(things == 'Blue - MC')
> ( s <- c(strsplit(things[-w], " - ", fixed = TRUE), things[w]) )
#[[1]]
#[1] "thing1" "thing2"

#[[2]]
#[1] "thingA" "thingB"

#[[3]]
#[1] "thingC"

#[[4]]
#[1] "Blue - MC"
```

Then if you only want the first of each of those,

```
> sapply(s, "[", 1)
#[1] "thing1" "thingA" "thingC" "Blue - MC"
```

Comment: If I do strsplit, how can i get it to split at every ' - ' except for 'Blue - MC'?

Comment: @TiffBrender How would we know not to split "Blue - MC". What makes that different from "Blue - MC". This strsplit suggestion sure is a good one.

Comment: @TiffBrender, I added that to the answer, but please revise the  question to include you don't want `Blue - MC`.

Comment: @Richard Scriven, it is in the question, but it is slightly buried. Thanks for the help. I chose to go with strsplit, splitting on '(?!Blue)\\s-\\s(?!MC)'. Thanks!

Comment: @TiffBrender Note that will also not split "Red - MC".

Answer (score 1):

When I want to capture parts of a message, I like to use the [regcapturedmatches.R](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321) helper function. I would use it like this

```
v <- c("thing1 - thing2", "thingalone","Blue-MC","1 - 2")
m <- gregexpr('^(.*?)(?:\\s-\\s(.*))?$', v, perl=T)
regmatches(v, m)
do.call(rbind, regcapturedmatches(v,m))
```

That returns

```
     [,1]         [,2]    
[1,] "thing1"     "thing2"
[2,] "thingalone" ""      
[3,] "Blue-MC"    ""      
[4,] "1"          "2"
```

Which I believe satisfies your expectations.